# Is it a bad practice to have local variable name same as parameter name in c?

Tags: c, scope, local-variables

For example, in the below code scope of local variable num should be only within else but is it a bad practice?

```
typedef enum
{
   FIRST,
   SECOND,
   THIRD,
} numbers;

void fun(int check, numbers *num)
{
    if (check)
    {
    ..........
    .......
    }
    else
    {
        numbers num;
        ............
    }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely unnecessarily confusing and error itinerary. Why do something like that?

Comment: Generally it is bad practice. The only exception is when you have a struct passed and need to initialize it's members. You can then name the parameters the very same names as the struct members, because they reside in different namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man gcc

-Wshadow
Warn whenever a local variable or type declaration shadows another variable, parameter, type, or class member (in C++), or whenever a built-in function
is shadowed. Note that in C++, the compiler warns if a local variable shadows an explicit typedef, but not if it shadows a struct/class/enum.

Comment: Is your answer yes or no, then? Also the question is about C, not C++.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, absolutely bad practice. Of course it will work so there is nothing inherently wrong with this approach, from the compilers/programs point of view. How ever as your project grows larger and more complex, keeping this practice up will surely lead to a harder debugging phase, a semi obfuscated readability and over all worse documentation.
If you do this and pick up your complex software after a few months, you will hate your self :)

Naming in software is a sensitive topic and every developer has their own standards and personal preferences. I myself try to write code that is self explanatory. Using long descriptive easy to understand variable / function names is my go to.

You might find some more reasons as to why you want to avoid certain things, in various code standards such as [SEI](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/downloads/secure-coding/assets/sei-cert-c-coding-standard-2016-v01.pdf) or [Barr](https://barrgroup.com/sites/default/files/barr_c_coding_standard_2018.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice for the name to match exactly, however, I routinely see, and use, the same but with the type having an Uppercase letter:

```
void func(Person person) { };
```

Types and variable have completely different jobs, and you want to be able to see the difference. Additionally, you want the IDE to be able to "Find All References", or jump to the class. Some frameworks rely upon the casing as well, to get things right, even if the language itself doesn't really mind.

From a language-only perspective, you will get more confused as the program gets larger, and you start trying to scroll or use "Find" or Jump To in the IDE. Even without the IDE problems, you won't know what's going on at any given time and you may end up editing the wrong part of code to fix a bug somewhere else.

I'd like to add that in many books, I see constructors written like this:

```
private int x, y;

MyClass(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

I personally don't like this, but it seems to be a choice between that, or changing the private variable name. Microsoft likes to put an underscore.